# Realm - Inserting an entry without duplicates

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a class called **Person** and inside the person I got **School** object,
the person model looks like this:

```
@PrimaryKey
var personId: String? = null 
.
...other properties
.
var school: School? = null
```

When I'm inserting a new **Person** into the db, first I'm creating a new **School** object then assign it to the **Person**, and finally inserting the **Person** to the db, this way the realm is creating a school entry into the **School** table then assigning to the **Person** entry, is it possible to create the **School** variable only inside **Person** object without inserting onto the **School** object table. I don't need **School** object as duplicate on different places.

Here is the user story:

I want to add a new person to our db, and when I fill all properties of the person, there is a drop down where I can choose the school person belongs to, this way when I insert the new Person into the table besides the name, surname and other fields there should be inserted also the selected school from drop down.

Answer (score 0):

i cant understand your question but if you mean u want to create person without declaring a school object inside , u can , and it will be null.
you can create a new person inside your realm transaction , and later add/modify properties of that by calling its personId.
**and use UUID.randomUUID().toString() for personId , not null;**